# Как полностью удалить VM Bitrix?

Tags: битрикс, виртуальная-машина

Необходимо удалённо решить проблему - удалить виртуальную машину Bitrix, накатить новую и развернуть бекап. Всё кроме "удалить VMB" я могу сделать. Но как её удалить со всеми конфигами и прочим мусором?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переустановите операционную систему на виртуальной машине. Это очистит все данные. Удаления окружения не предусмотрено так как в нем идет множество пакетов с зависимостями.

Comment: А я хотел бы удалённо удалить. Не вариант да?( А как же тогда на vps всё это работает?

Comment: Переустановка ОС через панель. Любая панель управления сервером имеет опцию переустановки или новой установки ОС.